# Problema al enviar imagen por AJAX a PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un formulario de PHP, que actualiza los datos del usuario y dentro esos datos a actualizar tiene una archivo de una imagen. **El formulario se envia por AJAX hacia un archivo PHP. 
Tengo problema al recibir la imagen que se envia por AJAX**

Este es mi codigo JS

```
        $("#form-edit-user").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            let name = $("#nombreActualizado").val();
            let apellido = $("#apellido").val();
            let email = $("#email").val();
            let password = $("#password").val();
            let foto = $("#foto").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                // dataType: "JSON",
                url: "../php/functions/functions.php",
                data: 
                {
                    name : name,
                    apellido : apellido,
                    email : email,
                    password : password,
                    foto : foto,
                    action: "actualizarPanelUser"
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data)
                    $(".div-mensajes p").html(data.validacion);
                    $(".div-mensajes p").addClass(data.alert);
                }
            })
        })
});
```

Este es PHP que recibe los datos de AJAX

```
  case "actualizarPanelUser":


                        $name = htmlentities(trim( $_POST["name"] ));
                        $apellido = htmlentities(trim( $_POST["apellido"] ));
                        $email = htmlentities(trim( $_POST["email"] ));
                        $password = htmlentities(trim( $_POST["password"] ));
                        $foto = $_POST["foto"]; // Intente por POST
                        $foto = $_FILES["foto"]; // Intente por FILES

                        var_dump($foto["name"]);


                    break;
```

**Cuando de la hago print_r a la imagen, simplemente esta vacia**
***Gracias***

Answer (score 1):

debes enviarlo con un [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData)

ejemplo:

```
$("#form-edit-user").on("submit", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

let form = new FormData(document.getElementById('#form-edit-user'));
//let name = $("#nombreActualizado").val();
//let apellido = $("#apellido").val();
//let email = $("#email").val();
//let password = $("#password").val();
//let foto = $("#foto").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // dataType: "JSON",
    url: "../php/functions/functions.php",
    data: form,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $(".div-mensajes p").html(data.validacion);
        $(".div-mensajes p").addClass(data.alert);
    }
})
})
});
```

y recibes la imagen con file: `$foto = $_FILES["foto"];`

Comment: Hola. Gracias por responderme. Copie exactamente como me lo distes y me genera este error => TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor is not an object. Estuve buscando por internet y me encontre que debia agregar ciertas opciones al AJAX (  data:postData, contentType:false, proccessData:false, ) pero aun asi, no funciona

Comment: Sobra la almohadilla al utilizar getElementById